# Cimg and itk image

Tags: c++, opencv, itk, cimg

I have a Cimg image and I want to use it with ITK (for registration). How can I create a ITK image from this Cimg image. Also can I want to create an OpenCV image from a ITK image? So can I use these libraries together?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: what is cimg, what is itk ? you will have to explain.

Comment: CImg: http://cimg.sourceforge.net/ ITK: http://www.itk.org/

Comment: @berak Dude, don't you sleep... ever? ;)

Comment: i will, like in half an hour.

Comment: So can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ITK class OpenCVImageBridge will be useful in converting ITK images to OpenCV images:

http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1OpenCVImageBridge.html

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Cool Image, and so cannot be helpful for the first part of the question.  ITK can read a large number of image types--png, dcm, mha, tiff, bmp, etc--your best bet is likely to look down the list of image types that Cimg can write, and find one that ITK can read.